# How to config [mode]="'sql'" use ng2-ace-editor in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, ace-editor

When I use ng2-ace-editor. have config

```
<div ace-editor
       [(text)]="text"
       [mode]="'sql'"
       [theme]="'eclipse'"
       [options]="options"
       [readOnly]="false"
       [autoUpdateContent]="true" 
       [durationBeforeCallback]="1000"
       (textChanged)="onChange($event)"
       style="min-height: 20px; max-height: 20px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"></div>
```

But have console.log

```
http://localhost:4200/mode-sql.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:4200/mode-html.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

How to config mode in ng2-ace-editor?

Comment: Could you add more info about the way you load ace, from the error it looks like the basePath is not configured correctly

Comment: I add ace in angular.json of project angular with angular-cli
I don't understand operation mechanism of ace in angular 7 for custom 1 mode.

Comment: looks like a bug in the https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor package, as the error is thrown even in the sample in the repo, try reporting the issue on github

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the required `modes/themes` that you are using in your editor.

Put this code in the component that uses the `Ace editor` and try again:

```
import 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/sql';
```